# How to check a request is from local host with ASP.NET technic

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am implementing a private page where it's only public to request from **local hosts** rather than exterior ones.

What technical stacks may I employ to check the request sources? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can check it with the bool property Request.IsLocal

Comment: mind you that probably does return Request.UserHostAddress == "127.0.0.1" in the background :)